# runqueue length in vmstat and sar

Tags: sar, vmstat

i am looking at the vmstat output to assess certain performance degradation on our systems, specifically for long runqueue. i find frequently it looks like this on a 8 CPU m/c:

Mon Jun 13 12:14:02 2016 procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu------
Mon Jun 13 12:14:02 2016  r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st

Mon Jun 13 12:14:02 2016  4  0      0 15270068 1280508 12915056    0    0     0   100 10633 33907 10  8 82  0  0
Mon Jun 13 12:14:12 2016  3  0      0 15269820 1280508 12915308    0    0     0   102 10509 35014 10  8 82  0  0
Mon Jun 13 12:14:22 2016  2  0      0 15269820 1280508 12915568    0    0     0   100 10632 36260 11  8 82  0  0
Mon Jun 13 12:14:32 2016  5  0      0 15269448 1280508 12915828    0    0     0    95 10247 34199  9  7 84  0  0
Mon Jun 13 **12:14:42 2016  8**  0      0 15278872 1280508 12906312    0    0     0   130 10771 35063 10  8 83  0  0
Mon Jun 13 12:14:52 2016  6  0      0 15278624 1280508 12906556    0    0     0    98 10810 36104 11  8 81  0  0
Mon Jun 13 12:15:02 2016  1  0      0 15278128 1280508 12906824    0    0     0   106 11094 35502 11  8 81  0  0
Mon Jun 13 12:15:12 2016  4  0      0 15278128 1280516 12907080    0    0     0   111 10557 33806  9  7 83  0  0
Mon Jun 13 12:15:22 2016  2  0      0 15277632 1280524 12907316    0    0     0   112 10785 36547 11  8 81  0  0
Mon Jun 13 12:15:32 2016  2  0      0 15277508 1280524 12907576    0    0     0    96 10726 35535 10  8 82  0  0
Mon Jun 13 12:15:42 2016  4  0      0 15277260 1280524 12907848    0    0     0   104 10209 32558  9  7 84  0  0
Mon Jun 13 12:15:52 2016  2  0      0 15276888 1280524 12908116    0    0     0   108 10857 37032 10  8 82  0  0
Mon Jun 13 12:16:02 2016  4  0      0 15276696 1280524 12908312    0    0     0    96 9917 33991  9  7 83  0  0
Mon Jun 13 12:16:12 2016  2  0      0 15276504 1280524 12908612    0    0     0    96 9673 31575  9  7 84  0  0
Mon Jun 13 12:16:22 2016 13  0      0 15276392 1280524 12908852    0    0     0    96 9820 35383  9  7 84  0  0
Mon Jun 13 12:16:32 2016  4  0      0 15275772 1280524 12909120    0    0     0   105 10490 35719 10  8 82  0  0
Mon Jun 13 12:16:42 2016  6  0      0 15276020 1280524 12909360    0    0     0   105 10732 33434 10  7 83  0  0
Mon Jun 13 12:16:52 2016  1  0      0 15270788 1280524 12909592    0    0     0    98 10011 35487  9  7 84  0  0
**Mon Jun 13 12:17:02 2016 11**  0      0 15275092 1280524 12909884    0    0     0   114 10643 36631 10  8 82  0  0

Mon Jun 13 12:17:12 2016  4  0      0 15275464 1280524 12910148    0    0     0    96 10649 33390 10  7 83  0  0
**Mon Jun 13 12:17:22 2016 11**  0      0 15274596 1280524 12910408    0    0     0   104 10607 36475 10  8 82  0  0

Mon Jun 13 12:17:52 2016 12  0      0 15276680 1280524 12901428    0    0     0   102 10690 36078 11  9 81  0  0

Mon Jun 13 12:18:02 2016  3  0      0 15277052 1280528 12901688    0    0     0    99 10793 36164 11  8 81  0  0

Mon Jun 13 12:18:12 2016  1  0      0 15276060 1280528 12901936    0    0     0   110 10535 33704 10  7 83  0  0
Mon Jun 13 12:18:22 2016  5  0      0 15275688 1280528 12902192    0    0     0   101 10599 35153 10  8 82  0  0
**Mon Jun 13 12:18:32 2016  0  0**      0 15275620 1280528 12902448    0    0     0    94 10051 35292  9  7 83  0  0
Mon Jun 13 12:18:42 2016  7  0      0 15275496 1280528 12902712    0    0     0   101 10278 33878  9  7 84  0  0

Mon Jun 13 12:43:32 2016 13  0      0 15170236 1280584 12921492    0    0     0    99 9798 35555  9  7 84  0  0
Mon Jun 13 12:43:42 2016  8  0      0 15169616 1280584 12921752    0    0     0    95 9748 33785  9  7 84  0  0
Mon Jun 13 12:43:52 2016  4  0      0 15176184 1280584 12921952    0    0     0   144 9882 33844 10  7 83  0  0
Mon Jun 13 12:44:02 2016 10  0      0 15176052 1280584 12922260    0    0     0   104 9468 34687  9  7 84  0  0
Mon Jun 13 12:44:12 2016  0  0      0 15175804 1280584 12922488    0    0     0    96 9231 32830  9  7 85  0  0
Mon Jun 13 12:44:22 2016 13  0      0 15175212 1280584 12922764    0    0     0    92 10051 33812  9  7 83  0  0
Mon Jun 13 12:44:32 2016  0  0      0 15175716 1280584 12923020    0    0     0   115 9402 35465  8  7 85  0  0
Mon Jun 13 12:44:42 2016  1  0      0 15174972 1280584 12923308    0    0     0   106 9946 34740 10  7 83  0  0
Mon Jun 13 12:44:52 2016  5  0      0 15171724 1280584 12923536    0    0     0    96 9123 31900  8  6 85  0  0

i've emphasized the timestamps 12:14:42, 12:17:02, 12:17:22, etc. to point out the #procs in runquue

when i look at the times close to this in sar, i don't see similarly long runqueue as below:

--
29920:Mon Jun 13 12:14:42 2016 12:14:32      runq-sz  plist-sz   ldavg-1   ldavg-5  ldavg-15

### 29921-Mon Jun 13 12:14:42 2016 12:14:42           10      1236      2.71      2.90      3.02

37740:Mon Jun 13 12:18:32 2016 12:18:22      runq-sz  plist-sz   ldavg-1   ldavg-5  ldavg-15

### 37741-Mon Jun 13 12:18:32 2016 12:18:32           12      1239      3.30      2.92      2.99

91460:Mon Jun 13 12:44:52 2016 12:44:42      runq-sz  plist-sz   ldavg-1   ldavg-5  ldavg-15

### 91461-Mon Jun 13 12:44:52 2016 12:44:52           11      1240      3.60      3.52      3.35

110160:Mon Jun 13 12:54:02 2016 12:53:52      runq-sz  plist-sz   ldavg-1   ldavg-5  ldavg-15

### 110161-Mon Jun 13 12:54:02 2016 12:54:02           11      1236      3.26      3.11      3.16

could someone explain why i have a seeming discrepancy between the two.

thanks for the response
S.R.

Comment: Couldn't it simply be that more jobs are run around those times?  That is just a few more processes than on average so it could be a really simple job.

Comment: yes, there could be a few more processes. however, my question is the difff in runq shown by sar and vmstat for the same time stamp. only at the 4 instances i posted above, sar shows runq length of any significance while vmstat has a number of instances with runq length over 10.  e.g.,                    at Mon Jun 13 12:14:42 2016 12:14:42, sar shows runq length of 10 while

Comment: yes, possibly few more processes. but, why is the diff in runq shown by sar and vmstat for the same timestamp. only at 4 instances i posted above, sar shows runq length of any significance while vmstat has a number of instances with runq length over 10.  e.g.,           from sar:   Mon Jun 13 12:17:02 2016 12:16:52      runq-sz  plist-sz   ldavg-1   ldavg-5  ldavg-15
Mon Jun 13 12:17:02 2016 12:17:02            7      1236      2.29      2.76      2.96  and from vmstat:  Mon Jun 13 12:17:02 2016 11 0 0 15275092 1280524 12909884 0 0 0 114 10643 36631 10 8 82. don't they use same krnl counters?

Comment: Is it possible that one counts the threads and the other just separate processes?